# Stripe - Update default card

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I am trying to allow the user to update their default payment method after they add it. I am getting this in Firebase Functions: `Error: No such source: card_1EhmibFZW9pBNLO2aveVfEm6`.

This leads me to believe that I need to pass `default_source` a `src_XXX...` id rather than a `card_XXX...` id. Anyone have an idea on this?

**Firebase Function:**

```
// Update Stripe default card based on user choice
exports.updateDefaultSource = functions.firestore
  .document("users/{userId}")
  .onUpdate(async (change, context) => {
    const newValue = change.after.data();
    const previousValue = change.before.data();
    console.log("previousValue.default_source: "+previousValue.default_source)
    console.log("newValue.default_source: "+newValue.default_source)
    if (
      previousValue.default_source &&
      newValue.default_source !== previousValue.default_source
    ) {
      // this triggers on every update to profile (more overhead), can we reduce this?
      try {
        console.log("newValue.default_source: "+newValue.default_source)
        const response = await stripe.customers.update(
          previousValue.customer_id,
          { default_source: newValue.default_source },
          (err, customer) => {
            console.log(err);
          }
        );
        return console.log("Response from Stripe update: " + response);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        await change.ref.set(
          { error: userFacingMessage(error) },
          { merge: true }
        );
        return reportError(error, { user: context.params.userId });
      }
    }
  });
```

**Firebase Function logs after I add the second Card to account:**
[image]

Comment: Hi DangerDoug,
The `default_source` field supports attached cards on the Customer, i.e. Card objects (e.g. card_123). 
Most likely, the card ID you are trying to set as the `default_source` isn't a Card ID among the Customer's existing sources. Are you updating the same Customer? i.e. is previousValue.customer_id == newValue.customer_id?

Comment: @hmunoz Okay thats good to know and helps. I added the firebase function logs that are shown. I think this might have to do with the card data not being propagated in stripe yet. All the card details are correct in DB, including the card number in the error. In the case of addPaymentSource, I really dont need the updateDefaultSource to trigger since Stripe automatically does that. How do I prevent updateDefaultSource from triggering in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this error solved itself, not 100% sure on how, but my guess is it had to do with Redux and/or Redux Persist not having everything loaded into the store.

My main question was answered by @hmunoz on whether or not the default_source accepted the card_123 type, which it does.